# Why do a ring expand radially on rotating it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, centripetal-force, elasticity, centrifugal-force

The reason told to me is due to centrifugal force. But centrifugal force is a pseudo force so how can we observe its effects like increasing radius of ring in other frame. Also as per me due to centripetal force the ring should contract. I am now confused. Should we see elongation through centrifugal force or centripetal force that is through inertial frame or non-inertial frame? Someone please explain me.

Answer (score 2):

As the ring starts spinning up, inertia attempts to rip the ring apart. The tension forces trying to hold the ring together arises because the ring is already trying to move apart, and the strain can only happen if there are stresses associated.

Those tension forces make up the centripetal acceleration.

i.e. you got the logic wrong. It is

1. inertially expand
2. expansion causes centripetal forces to arise and equal to what is needed
3. steady state of constant rotation with steady constant expansion and constant centripetal accelerations

You cannot have centripetal forces appearing out of nowhere, causing things to contract.

Comment: Thanks for the reason. But how should I see the ring for solving questions? Like should I solve using centrifugal force or through centripetal force for finding elongation in radius. Or both approaches are correct

Comment: Note that no part of my answer invoked centrifugal anything. There is no circumstance whereby a layperson would be better off using that concept. It is always confusing people. Leave it to the experts.

Answer (score 0):

Centrifugal force is a pseudo-force for an inertial observer that can easily relate it to centripetal acceleration in a curved motion.

At every moment, all the points would move on their tangent lines if "immediately released" from the medium. What's keeping the points together is the interaction with the surrounding points, through stress.

Let's write the local balance of momentum of a material particle

\begin{equation}
  \rho \mathbf{a} = \rho \mathbf{g} + \nabla \cdot \mathbb{T} \ ,
\end{equation}

Neglecting gravity and other "true" volume forces, $\mathbf{g} = \mathbf{0}$, and prescribing that all the particles are prescribing steady circular motion, the acceleration of a point $P$ at distance $r$ from the axis of rotation reads $\mathbf{a} = \Omega \times \Omega \times \mathbf{r}$,
\begin{equation}
 \rho \Omega \times \Omega \times \mathbf{r} = \nabla \cdot \mathbb{T} \ .
\end{equation}
Choosing a set of polar vectors with $\mathbf{\hat{z}}$ pointing in the same direction of $\Omega$, $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$ pointing from the axis to $P$ (and orthogonal to $\mathbf{\hat{z}}$, and $\mathbf{\hat{\theta}}$ the tangential vector forming a right-hand vector basis, it's easy to get

\begin{equation}
  \rho \Omega \times \Omega \times \mathbf{r} = \Omega^2 r \, \mathbf{\hat{z}} \times \underbrace{\left( \mathbf{\hat{z}} \times \mathbf{\hat{r}} \right)}_{\mathbf{\hat{\theta}}} = - \Omega^2 r \mathbf{\hat{r}} \ .
\end{equation}

Since the component of the divergence of the stress tensor $\mathbb{T}$ in the radial direction is negative, this indicates a strain in radial direction. To be more explicit, we could evaluate the divergence of a rank-2 tensor using cylindrical coordinates (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensors_in_curvilinear_coordinates), to get

\begin{equation}
  \nabla \cdot \mathbb{T} =  \mathbf{\hat{r}} \left( \dfrac{\partial T_{rr}}{\partial r} + \dfrac{1}{r}\left[ \dfrac{\partial T_{r\theta}}{\partial \theta} + T_{rr} - T_{\theta \theta} \right] + \dfrac{\partial T_{z,r}}{\partial z} \right) + \dots \ ,
\end{equation}
assuming no dependence on coordinates $\theta$, $z$,

\begin{equation}
  \nabla \cdot \mathbb{T} = 
\mathbf{\hat{r}} \left( \dfrac{\partial T_{rr}}{\partial r} + \dfrac{1}{r} \left( T_{rr} - T_{\theta \theta} \right) \right) 
+ \mathbf{\hat{\theta}} \left( \dfrac{\partial T_{r\theta}}{\partial r} + \dfrac{1}{r} (T_{r \theta} + T_{\theta r}) \right) 
+ \mathbf{\hat{z}} \left( \dfrac{\partial T_{rz}}{\partial r} + \dfrac{T_{rz}}{r} \right) 
\end{equation}

*I'm a bit busy now, I'll end the answer as soon as possible*